# Flex Native Extension with Dropbox API for Android

Tags: android, apache-flex, api, dropbox, air-native-extension

I´m trying to develop a Native Extension for Flex in order to use the Dropbox API for Android. I have already tried this dropbox-r33 module for FLEX but it`s deprecated for Android 4, so this is not a solution for me.

I have already an ANE with Vibration and Dropbox connection. Vibration works perfectly (example from the web) and I tried to include the functions to use Dropbox API for Android (I have already tested it in an Android project and it works).

The problem is that I´ve been force to unpack the classes from the .jars needed in the Dropbox API in order that my ANE recognizes them but I´m getting this error:

**05-29 12:02:21.489: I/ConnectionError(5798): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {air.TestVibrationExtension.debug/com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?**

where TestVibrationExtension is my ANE´s project name. My package name is air.extensions and in that folder I have included the unpacked dropbox api classes (under air.extension.com and air.extensions.org).

Who has worked with Dropbox API knows that in the AndroidManifest you have to include the following activity declaration:

```
        <activity
        android:name="com.dropbox.client2.android.AuthActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard"
        android:launchMode="singleTask" >
        <intent-filter>

            <!-- Change this to be db- followed by your app key -->
            <data android:scheme="db-myAppKey" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I think the error is related to that activity declaration but I don´t know what to do in order my ANE recognizes it.

Help please!

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question and I don't know if it fits your requirements but there's an AS3 Dropbox API for Air:http://code.google.com/p/dropbox-as3/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That is the dropbox-r33.swc module I mentioned. It works perfectly in its previous releases but release 3.3 doesn't work properly with Android 4. And I cannot use a previous release of this module because Dropbox doesn't allow it (problem with app token and secret version). But thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropbox-r33.swc module works but it is necessary to upload AIR library to it latest version. Doing it works on every Android platform perfectly.